# VB.Net Regex - How to replace all characters that follow after a pattern

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a string:

```
Dim fileName = "\something\folderName\subFolder\" + randomOtherStuff
```

And I need to replace `folderName\subFolder\` and anything following it until the end of the string, but I don't know what is in randomOtherStuff.

I am using `Regex.Replace(fileName, pattern, newValue)` but I do not know what the pattern should be. I know I need to somehow escape the backslash, and I need a way of capturing any character that follows.

Any advice on how to do this using Visual Basic code would be great.

Comment: Yes, in a regex pattern, you need to use ``\\`` to match a backslash. And to match any char(s), use `.*`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  `Regex.Replace(fileName, "something\\subFolder\\.*", newValue)` is what I attempted to do and everything works except the `.*` part does not get replaced.

Comment: That is impossible. Please add the whole relevant code to the question. And what does `randomOtherStuff` hold?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is all the relevant code. It is in a function whose only responsibility is to replace this pattern for the new string value. `randomOtherStuff` might include `"fileName.txt"`, or `"folder/something/fileName.jpg"` for example.

Comment: What is impossible about this?

Comment: `.*` matches any character but a newline zero or more times. Can your URLs contain newlines?

Comment: Nope definitely not. It seems to just be replacing the first character it finds and not every character till the very end of fileName.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/xkxSOv - everything works well. Did you really want to use `"something\\subFolder\\.*"` or `"folderName\\subFolder\\.*"`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew got it working thank you. I had a problem in the randomOtherStuff like you mentioned. This fileName comes from a server so I had to do some debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `(?s)\\folderName\\subFolder\\.*` pattern to remove the `\folderName\subFolder\` substring and anything following it:

```
Dim fileName = "\something\folderName\subFolder\randomOtherStuff"
Dim newValue = "<NEW_VALUE>"
Dim res = Regex.Replace(fileName, "(?s)\\folderName\\subFolder\\.*", "\" & newValue)
```

See the [VB.NET demo](https://ideone.com/xkxSOv).

Note that `(?s)` is the same as `RegexOptions.Singleline` that enable a `.` to match newline symbols (that are not matched with `.` by default).